# How to efficiently check if an element is in a list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists as follws.

```
mylist = [[5274919, ["report", "porcelain", "firing", "technic"]], [5274920, ["implantology", "dentistry"]], [52749, ["method", "recognition", "long", "standing", "root", "perforation", "molar"]], [5274923, ["exogenic", "endogenic", "cause", "tooth", "jaw", "anomaly", "method", "method", "standing"]]]
```

I also have a list of concepts as follows.

```
myconcepts = ["method", "standing"]
```

I want to see how many times each concept in `myconcepts` is in `mylist` records. i.e.;

```
"method" = 2 times in records (i.e. in `52749` and `5274923`)
"standing" = 2 times in records
```

My current code is as follows.

```
mycounting = 0
for concept in myconcepts:
  for item in mylist:
     if concept in item[1]:
       mycounting = mycounting + 1
print(mycounting)
```

However, my current `mylist` is very very large and have about 5 million records. `myconcepts` list have about 10000 concepts.

In my current code it takes nearly 1 minute for a concept to get the `count`, which is very slow.

I would like to know the most efficient way of doing this in python?

For testing purposes I have attached a small portion of my dataset in: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z6FsBtLyDZClod9hK8nK4syivZToa7ps/view?usp=sharing

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: That depends on your usage.  If you're going to do this many times, it pays to use a flattened list, and either use a `Counter` object (a type of dict), or use the `count` method on the flattened list.  These techniques are already documented well on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.

Comment: can you change the lists to sets? Searching sets is O(1) instead of O(n)

Comment: With that many records you might reconsider your data structure.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I am happy to change the structure of `mylist`

Comment: EmJ, is converting you information into a database a possible answer? If so i'll show you how to add you data to mongodb for a quick search answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting approach 3 from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-count-the-sublists-containing-given-element-in-a-list/

```
from itertools import chain 
from collections import Counter 

mylist = [[5274919, ["report", "porcelain", "firing", "technic"]], [5274920, ["implantology", "dentistry"]], [52749, ["method", "recognition", "long", "standing", "root", "perforation", "molar"]], [5274923, ["exogenic", "endogenic", "cause", "tooth", "jaw", "anomaly", "method", "method", "standing"]]]

myconcepts = ["method", "standing"]

def countList(lst, x):
" Counts number of times item x appears in sublists "
    return Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(i[1]) for i in lst))[x] 

# Use dictionary comprehension to apply countList to concept list
result = {x:countList(mylist, x) for x in myconcepts}
print(result) # {'method':2, 'standing':2}
```

*Revised current method (compute counts only once) *

```
def count_occurences(lst):
    " Number of counts of each item in all sublists "
    return Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(i[1]) for i in lst))

cnts = count_occurences(mylist)
result = {x:cnts[x] for x in myconcepts}
print(result) # {'method':2, 'standing':2}
```

**Performance (comparing posted methods using Jupyter Notebook)**

Results show this method and Barmar posted method are close (i.e. 36 vs 42 us)

The improvement to the current method reduced to time approximately in half (i.e. from 36 us to 19 us).  This improvement should be even more substantial for a larger number of concepts (i.e. problem has > 1000 concepts).

However, the original method is faster at 2.55 us/loop.

*Method current method*

```
%timeit { x:countList(mylist, x) for x in myconcepts}
#10000 loops, best of 3: 36.6 µs per loop

Revised current method:

%%timeit
cnts = count_occurences(mylist)
result = {x:cnts[x] for x in myconcepts}
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.4 µs per loop
```

*Method 2 (from Barmar post)*

```
%%timeit
r = collections.Counter(flatten(mylist))
{i:r.get(i, 0) for i in myconcepts}
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 42.7 µs per loop
```

*Method 3 (Original Method)*

```
%%timeit

result = {}
for concept in myconcepts:
  mycounting = 0
  for item in mylist:
     if concept in item[1]:
       mycounting = mycounting + 1
  result[concept] = mycounting
  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.55 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does using `chain` and `counter` improve performance? :)

Comment: @Emj--about to test performance.  Will update the post in the next few minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Sure, I look forward to see your update :)

Comment: Thank you. I will run your method in my rea dataset and let you know the performance from my side. Give me an few hours for testing :)

Comment: @emj--check my updated post where I added your original method.  Surprisingly the original is fastest.  Wonder if it depends upon the size of the dataset (i.e. original is faster for small datasets).

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Yes, I think the performance depends on the size. I will run your code for my dataset and let you know how thing went. Thank you very much. In the meantime, if you get any idea to further improve. please let me know :)

Comment: Yes, you were correct. The original method takes me about 1 minute to process one concept. However, the current method takes about 1.5 minutes to process (which is surprising as the original code is just a naive method) :(

Comment: @EmJ--good feedback.  Let me see if I can remove the overhead of computing sets for every concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: @emj--check revised method that uses count_occurences.  This should be a lot faster for your test case.

Comment: wow, i think that is a smart idea. yes, it should definitely save a lot of time. I will try this in my dataset and let you know. thanks a lot for your great idea. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: How is this performance? `2600/2600 [00:04<00:00, 627.22it/s]` :) Thank you so much. It works like magic. Thank you :)

Comment: Please let me know your thoughts on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830182/how-to-get-elements-efficiently-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python It is similar to this question, with tuples in the list :)

Comment: @emj--just saw your post.  Looks like you have already found a good solution.

Comment: Thank you for your support. The program that took days and days to run takes now only takes few minutes to run. Yes, I got a good solution for my other question too. Thank you very much. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the input and then use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
myconcepts = ["method", "standing"]
mylist = [[5274919, ["report", "porcelain", "firing", "technic"]], [5274920, ["implantology", "dentistry"]], [5274921, ["method", "recognition", "long", "standing", "root", "perforation", "molar"]], [5274923, ["exogenic", "endogenic", "cause", "tooth", "jaw", "anomaly", "method", "standing"]]]
def flatten(d):
  for i in d:
    yield from [i] if not isinstance(i, list) else flatten(i)

r = collections.Counter(flatten(mylist))
result = {i:r.get(i, 0) for i in myconcepts}
```

Output:

```
{'method': 2, 'standing': 2}
```

---

Edit: record lookup:

```
result = {i:sum(i in b for _, b in mylist) for i in myconcepts}
```

Output:

```
{'method': 2, 'standing': 2}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am looking how many times each concept is in `mylist` records (not the total count). For example, `method` appears in two records `52749` and `5274923` (please see my edited question). Thank you :)

Comment: @EmJ Are you trying to find the record names that have a corresponding value in `myconcepts`? The current result `{'method': 2, 'standing': 2}` is indeed the individual counts for each element in `myconcepts`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I want to find the `number of records` that each concept is in. For example consider a record like this; `[5274923, ["exogenic", "endogenic", "cause", "tooth", "jaw", "anomaly", "method", "method", "standing"]`. It has `method` 2 times. However, the number of records is 1. :)

Comment: @EmJ Please see my recent edit, as I added a solution to find the unique records that store a target value.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. However, I only need a count of number of records. For instance, {'method': 2, 'standing': 2} :)

Comment: @EmJ No problem. `{'method': 2, 'standing': 2}` is exactly the output provided by my first method, and to derive the desired dictionary from the second solution's output you can simply do `{a:len(b) for a, b in result.items()}`

Comment: Thank you :) However I feel like you still did not get what I meant. Please input this list to your first code and you will understand what I meant :) `mylist = [[5274919, ["report", "porcelain", "firing", "technic"]], [5274920, ["implantology", "dentistry"]], [52749, ["method", "recognition", "long", "standing", "root", "perforation", "molar"]], [5274923, ["exogenic", "endogenic", "cause", "tooth", "jaw", "anomaly", "method", "method", "standing"]]]` Th output should be `{'method': 2, 'standing': 2}`. However, the first method outputs `{'method': 3, 'standing': 2}`. :)

Comment: @EmJ Thank you for your comment. Please see my solution provided under "Edit:"

Comment: Thank you. Your edited answer is correct :) Is there a way to make it efficient or do you think that is it efficient than my current code?

Answer (score 1):

Change the concept lists to sets, so that searching will be O(1). You can then use intersection to count the number of matches in each set.

```
import set
mylist = [
    [5274919, {"report", "porcelain", "firing", "technic"}], 
    [5274920, {"implantology", "dentistry"}], 
    [52749, {"method", "recognition", "long", "standing", "root", "perforation", "molar"}], 
    [5274923, {"exogenic", "endogenic", "cause", "tooth", "jaw", "anomaly", "method", "method", "standing"}]
]
myconcepts = {"method", "standing"}
mycounting = 0
for item in mylist:
    mycounting += len(set.intersection(myconcepts, item[1]))
print(mycounting)
```

If you want to get the counts for each concept separately, you'll need to loop over `myconcept`, then use the `in` operator. You can put the results in a dictionary.

```
mycounting = {concept: sum(1 for l in mylist if concept in l[1]) for concept in myconcepts}
print(mycounting) // {'standing': 2, 'method': 2}
```

This will still be more efficient than using a list, because `concept in l[1]` is O(1).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get an error saying `NameError: name 'intersection' is not defined`. Do you know how to fix this? Thank you :)

Comment: Should be `set.intersection`.

Comment: By the way, you can do intersections and unions of sets using the overloaded `&` and `|` operators; I think it is more readable, personally.

Comment: @Barmar I get the answer of your code as `4`. But it should be `2` and `2`. :)

Comment: @kaya3 I knew that, but I thought this would be more self-explanatory.

Comment: @EmJ There's only one `mycounting` variable, it's not a separate counter for each concept.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the comment. Is it possible to get the count of each concept seperately using `intersection` or any other efficient method? :)