# How to get elements efficiently in a list of tuples in python

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples as follows.

```
mydata = [(5274919, ['report', 'porcelain', 'record', 'technic'], "[b'Dental Porcelain', b'Dentistry']"), (5274920, ['implantology', 'dentistry'], "[b'Dental Implantation', b'Dentistry']"), (5274921, ['record', 'recognition', 'long', 'standing', 'root', 'perforation', 'molar'], "[b'Dentistry', b'Molar', b'Root Canal Therapy', b'adverse effects']"), (5274923, ['exogenic', 'endogenic', 'cause', 'tooth', 'jaw', 'anomaly'], "[b'Dentistry', b'Jaw Abnormalities', b'etiology', b'Tooth Abnormalities', b'etiology']"), (5274922, ['obscure', 'facial pain', 'unnatural', 'occlusal', 'height'], "[b'Dental Occlusion, Traumatic', b'complications', b'Dentistry', b'Facial Neuralgia', b'etiology']"), (11636455, ['presenting', 'development', 'denmark'], "[b'Demography', b'Denmark']"), (12255310, ['study', 'human lactation'], "[b'Biology', b'Health', b'Lactation', b'Nutritional Physiological Phenomena', b'Physiology', b'Pregnancy', b'Research']"), (12255446, ['the effect', 'testosterone propionate', 'estradiol', 'given', 'combination', 'reproductive organ', 'gonadotrophin', 'presenting', 'pituitary', 'the rat'], "[b'Androgens', b'Animals, Laboratory']"), (12259009, ['carcinoma of the cervix', 'epidemiologic', 'study'], "[b'Age Factors', b'Behavior', b'Birth Rate', b'Coitus', b'Contraception', b'Contraception Behavior', b'Contraceptives, Postcoital', b'Demography', b'Disease', b'Education', b'Epidemiologic Methods', b'Family Planning Services', b'Fertility', b'Infection', b'Marital Status', b'Marriage', b'Neoplasms', b'Parity', b'Population', b'Population Characteristics', b'Population Dynamics', b'Religion', b'Reproduction', b'Research', b'Sexual Behavior', b'Sexually Transmitted Diseases', b'Social Class', b'Uterine Cervical Neoplasms']"), (12278329, ['clitoridectomy', 'downfall', 'isaac baker brown', 'f r c s'], "[b'Attitude', b'Behavior', b'Delivery of Health Care', b'Developed Countries', b'England', b'Europe', b'Health', b'Health Personnel', b'Physicians', b'Psychology', b'United Kingdom']")]
```

I also have a list of words as follows

```
mywords = ["presenting", "record"]
```

First I want to see if each word in `mywords` list appears in the tuple's second element. If so collect it's third element together.

So, the output should be;

```
presenting = [b'Demography', b'Denmark', b'Androgens', b'Animals, Laboratory']
record = [b'Dental Porcelain', b'Dentistry', b'Dentistry', b'Molar', b'Root Canal Therapy', b'adverse effects']
```

My current code is as follows

```
for word in mywords:
  my_keywords = []
  for item in mydata:
     if word in item[1]:
         my_keywords.append(ast.literal_eval(item[2]))
  print(mykeywords)
```

However, since `mydata` is very very huge (i.e. 1.8 million) it takes about 1.5 minutes to process one word in `mywords`, which is very slow. Please let me know an efficient way of doing this in python.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: If this code works, and you're just looking to improve it, I suggest instead posting over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think the question is more suitable here; it's not asking about general code quality, but specifically about algorithm efficiency.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the data, where it comes from, its format? There might be a better data structure for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you say *"`mydata` is very very huge"*, that means it is much bigger than the example data you've given in your question. Otherwise it is hard to imagine this taking minutes to run.

The algorithm can be improved by iterating through the list once, instead of just once per keyword. The trick is to test whether an item matches one or more keywords using a [set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection). In order to build separate result lists per keyword, we can store them in a dictionary. It's also only necessary to call `literal_eval` once per item, even if it matches multiple keywords.

```py
my_words = {"presenting", "record"}

results = { k: [] for k in my_words }

for item in mydata:
    matching_words = my_words & set(item[1])
    if matching_words:
        item_result = ast.literal_eval(item[2])
        for w in matching_words:
            results[w].append(item_result)

for word in my_words:
    print(results[word])
```

Note that `my_words` is now a set instead of a list.

Comment: That seems to put all the results in one list. It looks like there's supposed to be a different list for each keyword.

Comment: Oh, I see that the list is initialised to empty, and printed inside the loop, which slightly changes the solution. One moment.

Comment: @kaya3 I saw your answer just now. Thank you very much. The `mydata` list has about 1.8 million records. I will try the code you have provided and tell you if I got any performance improvement :)